# Add addition where clause in MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

I have the following clause

```
$curSong = $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM ".$wpdb->prefix . "current_requests WHERE id='".$_POST['remove']."'");
```

and id like to add where page_id = $postid to the WHERE clause

simple I know but its just the syntax I am a little unsure of

Thanks

Henry

Comment: from [`SELECT Syntax`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html) :: `In the WHERE expression, you can use any of the functions and operators that MySQL supports` - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/expressions.html. So `... WHERE expr AND expr ...` or `... WHERE expr OR expr ...`. and in your case `... WHERE id='".$_POST['remove']."' AND page_id=$postid`. note - you are open to sql injection due to directly using `$_POST` without sanitizing.

Comment: here is my problem in more detail... think I have bigger fish to fry than just adding a few extra where clauses...

http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4030/getting-page-id-into-my-plugin

Answer (score 1):

```
you can write sql command like
Delete FROM Table where id=123 AND page_id=789 AND route_id=567

as much as you want, you can add more conditions using 'AND' logical       
operator.
```

if it helps you mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

```
$query = sprintf("DELETE FROM %scurrent_requests WHERE id='%s' AND page_id='%s'", $wpdb->prefix, $_POST['remove'], $postid);
$curSong = $wpdb->query($query);
```

You can add more conditions to the where clause using "AND" operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
$curSong = $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM ".$wpdb->prefix . "current_requests WHERE id='".$_POST['remove']."' AND page_id='$postid'");
```

Comment: with a space at pageid = ?

Comment: Wouldn't make a difference if there's a space or not. I removed the spaces though.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code...

Validate the user value to prevent SQL injection

> Use `htmlspecialchars()` or `htmlentities()` by

```
$remove= htmlspecialchars($_POST['remove']);
$curSong = $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM ".$wpdb->prefix . "`current_requests` WHERE `id`='$remove' and `page_id` = '$postid'");
```

> Note: You can add many condition by using `and` `or` Operator...